# How can i remove a specific class on a selected element

Tags: jquery

On click of the Addons Button , and selection of checkboxes , a specific class namely

**ui-checkbox-on** is added dynamically  to the label element .

On click of Remove All , how can i remove all the added **ui-checkbox-on** class on the label tag

i have tried as

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function (e) {

    $("addonsWrap").each(function (index) {

        $elem = $(this);

        $elem.find("label").removeClass('ui-checkbox-on');

    }
    });
```

But nothing is happening , could you please let em know how to resolve this ??

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/99/

Comment: Typo in selector: `$("#addonsWrap")`. Also, IDs should be unique so you shouldn't be doing an `.each` on them

Comment: ya thanks but even though i replaced that with id , still its not removing the classes .

Comment: *ui-checkbox-on is added dynamically to the label element .* what is meant by it?

Comment: @Kiran In your fiddle there is no `ui-checkbox-on` class

Comment: You have syntax error regarding closing `each` loop, you should open your console in order to debug it...

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function (e) {
    $("#addonsWrap").find("label.ui-checkbox-on").removeClass('ui-checkbox-on');   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function (e) {

```
$('.ui-checkbox input[type=checkbox]').click();
```

});

Check this .I have tested this and found working fine.